# Python lxml iterating through tr elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml, lxml.html

I'm running into an issue when trying to get the parent node of a tr element whilst iterating through them all.

Here's a basic table that I'm working with.

> ```
>  <table border=1>
>     <tbody>
>     <tr>
>     <td>
>     <p>Some text</p>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>     <p>Some more text</p>
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>     <td>
>     <p> Some more text</p>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>     <p> Some more text</p>
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     <tr>
>     <td>
>     <p> Some more text</p>
>     </td>
>     <td>
>     <p> Some more text</p>
>     </td>
>     </tr>
>     </tbody>
>     </table>
> ```

And here's my Python script to get the parent node using lxml

```
import lxml.html

htm = lxml.html.parse('plaintable.htm')
tr = htm.xpath('//tr')
for x in tr:
    tbody = tr.getparent()
    if tbody.index(tr) == 1:
        print ('Success!')
print ('Finished')
```

I'm getting this error when I run the script:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'getparent'

I'm quite new to Python so it could be something simple I'm messing up. I read through the lxml documents and I couldn't find an answer.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` is actually a list of xpath matches. `x` corresponds to individual `tr` elements - call `getparent()` method on it instead:

```
tr = htm.xpath('//tr')
for x in tr:
    tbody = x.getparent()
    # ...
```

Though, I don't see much sense in getting the same parent over and over again in a loop, in case you have a single `table` and `tbody` element. Why don't locate it beforehand:

```
tbody = htm.xpath("//tbody")[0]
for x in tbody.xpath(".//tr"):
    # ...
```

---

> I need to find the first tr in every table to build it properly

As for this - I would iterate over all `table` elements and find the first `tr` element:

```
tables = htm.xpath("//table")
for table in tables:
    first_tr = table.xpath(".//tr")[0]
```

Comment: Ah perfect! I was misunderstanding how to call the index in the for loop. I'm used to JavaScript so was having a tough time. In a nutshell, I'm building an XML file based on the tables in the HTML document. I'm currently working with 36 different tables. I need to find the first tr in every table to build it properly

Comment: @Chad got it, also updated with a sample code for the "I need to find the first tr in every table to build it properly" part. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, that'll be tremendously helpful with creating the parent nodes. I really appreciate your help!